# URISyntaxException disables ability to create new GUI

Tags: java, exception, user-interface, static, uri

I've created separate class files in a package.

My issue is, in the `Gui.java` file, in order to enable hyper linking through the click of a button, I'd had to add throws `URISyntaxException` to my public Gui.

So in turn, it ended up looking like this:

```
public Gui() throws URISyntaxException {
    //Fancy gui code here
}
```

Now I thought that this would work out fine, but it actually created this error in my other class file that referenced the Gui:

### Code line

```
public static final Gui gui = new Gui();
```

### Compilation error

```
Unhandled exception type URISyntaxException
```

And now I have the inability to use this Gui. Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Please don't post links to images of what is actually textual information.  I've 'converted' the image to text and included the text as an edit.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  An SSCCE can have more than one class, but they all must be in one source file.  2)  `public static final Gui gui..` should probably not be declared `static`.  How best to create and use it, is best answered after viewing an SSCCE of the two classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things you can do to fix your problem:

Declare as a global variable and...

- initialize in a `static` block using a `try` and `catch` block.
- initialize it in a method/constructor using a `try` and `catch` block. (Alternatively, instead of using `try` and `catch` blocks, you could make it so that your method/constructor `throws` the `URISyntaxException` instead)

One other alternative is that you could find all occurences where in your `Gui` constructor the `URISyntaxException` is being thrown and put specifically that code under a `try` and `catch` block. (causing you to remove the `throws URISyntaxException` from your constructor which will allow you to declare and initialize how you are currently trying to do)

Comment: Just to verify that this worked, I went with adding a try and catch block which solved the problem completely. I put the newly set URI into the try block, as well as the call to the method, and the error completely vanished. Thank you. This was a very thorough answer, and if I could +1 this early into my stay here I would.